# Firebase performance monitor issue with support lib 26.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I am getting the below error in `com.google.firebase.firebase-perf` plugin.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity
>           at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.instrumentation.InstrumentationConfigFactory.setAppStartConfig(InstrumentationConfigFactory.java:70)
>           at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.instrumentation.InstrumentationConfigFactory.(InstrumentationConfigFactory.java:62)
>           at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.instrumentation.Instrument.(Instrument.java:34)
>           at com.google.firebase.perf.plugin.FirebaseTransform.transform(FirebaseTransform.java:192)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
>           at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:168)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>           ... 101 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
>           ... 120 more

I am using the following libs :

- com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1
- com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.0.4
- Support lib 26.0.0
- build tool version 26.0.1

*fyi : It is working fine below support lib 26

Comment: Please file a bug report at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/
It will help if you have a minimal project with source code that demonstrates  the problem.  I use all the same versions of everything, and I don't have any problems.

Comment: We are similar issue firebase performace library. Were you able to find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

We were facing similar issue. It was one of the libraries which was causing this issue. That library was still using ActionBarActivity in their code. It worked fine after removing that library.

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, you can create a proxy class in your project. Create a class named ActionBarActivity under same package name as it is there in support library and make it extend AppCompatActivity class.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue, but can't find ActionBarActivity in any of my libs. Which was the troublesome lib in your case?

Comment: @IshaanGarg, it was conflict with my internal third party dependency. you can create dependency graph and check.

Comment: @Tasneem Sorry but what should I be looking for in the dependency graph?

Comment: you can use gradle command for this, but it did not help me. I created demo project with all the dependencies and by removing them one by one :)  I know its very tedious. Or if any way you are able to figure out which third party apk is using ActionBarActivity then you are done.

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

This class was deprecated in API level 24.2.0.
Use AppCompatActivity instead.