# Firebase Performance integration issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I'm trying to add Firebase Performance Monitoring to the app

Here are my version numbers:

```
FIREBASE_VERSION = '2.3.0'
PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION = '11.2.0'
SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = '26.0.2'
BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = '26.0.1'
COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 26
TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 25 
MIN_SDK_VERSION = 19
```

Adding next two lines to the app-level build.gradle file:

```
//other code
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
//other code
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
```

leads to the next error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForProductionDebug'.
> android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity
```

Similar issue as in [Firebase performance monitor issue with support lib 26.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457921/firebase-performance-monitor-issue-with-support-lib-26-0-0)

This issue might be caused by some 3rd party lib, is there some way to determine which lib uses old support lib?

Comment: Where are you using FIREBASE_VERSION?

Comment: compile "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:$FIREBASE_VERSION"

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarActivity has been removed in 26.x of the support lib.
See the following to check your dependencies:
[Using gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've studied the project dependencies but haven't found the conflicts. It seems that the problem is in Firebase Performance lib (or in its build logic) because when I disable it the project compiles and runs successfully.

Comment: It's possible there's some weak dependency in the libraries you're using. If you file a support ticket at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/ with your gradle dependencies, we can help track down the offending library.